# Is there to have a parameter for an entire list?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, column, calculated-column, task-list

Is it possible to have an attribute, like start date, where other columns would use it to calculate their value?

For example the due date column would take the start date and then add the amount of date it takes (which is another column) to it.

I eventually would be referencing other tasks for their due date, but that's for another time.

Comment: What do you mean by attribute like start date? You mean a start date generated by system?

Comment: It would be a start date the project manager would decide/ enter in.

Comment: If the manager is entering in the start date in the form, then a column will be automatically created for that list. What do you need besides that?

Comment: That would mean having a column that would have the same value for each item in the list which seems pointless. The start date would refer to the start date of task list which is the start date of the project, not each task.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use another list to store your date in a dummy item. Then read that date from a workflow at creation of the item. Add the number of days you want to the source date and store it in your item.

- Custom List with a date column
- Dummy item with reference date
- SharePoint Designer Workflow on destination list, starts at creation
- Retrieve reference date from configuration list item
- Do calculation on reference date to add days and store it to variable
- Update list item date with variable